# React-based weather app

Tags: html, react.js, jsx

I am an experienced developer but pretty new to React. I wanted to go on my own and build a simple little weather app that updates the image, tempature, and description of each day when you click on the + or - buttons.

I got it to work but I think it is pretty messy and was hoping for some advice. Firstly, is it bad practice to create a state on a component from props passed in by its parent? I know I could set the values within the state but just decided to keep it the way i designed it initially (at first WeatherCard was a stateless component so i was pulling in props either way). However, I could only imagine that there would be a couple instances that this would be applicable...?

Also, I ran into a problem with injecting images, I was trying to use

```
<img src={'./folder/image.extension'}>
```

and then update the src but couldn't figure out how to do that, so I made the function getImage() to help me out. Is there a way you guys can think of to update the src of the image so I can get rid of getImage() and just update the state to a string (file path) that the src pulls from?

Lastly I am really baffled about how the description was reacting. The description would update at a different time than the image, which was not what I was expecting. If you look at the code you will see that I had to adjust the if statements in handleClick to a -1 and a +1 to make up for some kind of what seemed to be like a delay. I don't really understand the issue here, but thats how I compensated for it. What are your guys' thoughts?

Overall, I know this is probably some pretty junk code here but I intend on improving it. Will probably start from scratch and maybe it will go better for me but hoping for some advice!

---

#### WeatherCard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import sunny from '../img/sunny.png';
import partly from '../img/partly.png';
import cloudy from '../img/cloudy.png';
import rainy from '../img/rainy.png';

class WeatherCard extends Component {
    state = {
        day: this.props.data.day,
        temp: this.props.data.temp,
        description: this.props.data.description
    }

    getImage = () => {
        if (this.state.temp >= 95 ) {
            return <img src={ sunny } alt="sunny"></img>
        } else if (this.state.temp >= 85) {
            return <img src={ partly } alt="partly cloudy"></img>
        } else if (this.state.temp >= 75) {
            return <img src={ cloudy } alt="cloudy"></img>
        } else {
            return <img src={ rainy } alt="rainy"></img>
        }
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        if (e.target.innerHTML === '+') {
            this.setState(function(prevState, props){
                if (this.state.temp >= 94) {
                    return {description: 'Sunny'}
                } else if (this.state.temp >= 84) {
                    return {description: 'Partly Cloudy'}
                } else if (this.state.temp >= 74) {
                    return {description: 'Cloudy'}
                } else {
                    return {description: 'Rainy'}
                }
            });
            this.setState ({
                temp: (this.state.temp+1)
            });
        } else {
            this.setState(function(prevState, props){
                if (this.state.temp >= 96) {
                    return {description: 'Sunny'}
                } else if (this.state.temp >= 86) {
                    return {description: 'Partly Cloudy'}
                } else if (this.state.temp >= 76) {
                    return {description: 'Cloudy'}
                } else {
                    return {description: 'Rainy'}
                }
            });
            this.setState ({
                temp: (this.state.temp-1)
            });
        }
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-head">{ this.state.day }</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h1>{ this.state.temp }</h1>
                    { this.getImage() }
                    <p>{ this.state.description }</p>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <div className="upButton" onClick={ this.handleClick }>+</div>
                    <div className="downButton" onClick={ this.handleClick }>-</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default WeatherCard;
```

---

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WeatherCard from './components/WeatherCard';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        data : [
            {
                day : 'Monday',
                temp : 100,
                description : 'Sunny'
            },
            {
                day : 'Tuesday',
                temp : 100,
                description : 'Sunny'
            },
            {
                day : 'Wednesday',
                temp : 100,
                description : 'Sunny'
            },
            {
                day : 'Thursday',
                temp : 100,
                description : 'Sunny'
            },
            {
                day : 'Friday',
                temp : 100,
                description : 'Sunny'
            },
            {
                day : 'Saturday',
                temp : 100,
                description : 'Sunny'
            },
            {
                day : 'Sunday',
                temp : 100,
                description : 'Sunny'
            }
        ]
    }

    renderCards = () => {
        return this.state.data.map((card, i) => <WeatherCard key = {i} data = {this.state.data[i]}></WeatherCard>)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="cards">
                    { this.renderCards() }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The initial data**

Since every day shares the exact same default temperature, repeating it would be useless, you can instead map a list of days and create a JSON for each element using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The description should also be removed from your data, since it entirely depends on the temperature, there is no reason to store both `temp` and `description`.

```
this.state = {
    data: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday',].map(day => ({
        day,
        temp: 100
    }))
}
```

**Setting your initial state**

The React documentation recommends using a class contructor instead of setting your state raw into your class. This solution may wokr for now, but it can cause unexpected behavior on the long term.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        data: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday',].map(day => ({
            day,
            temp: 100
        }))
    }
}
```

**Getting the description and image**

Having blocks of `if/else` nested statements is almost never necessary when using JSON objects. Just create an array containing every possible description/image combination and which temperature it represent.

When done, use a [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to get get the corresponding description/image. This function will execute a verification (`weather => temp >= weather.value`) on every JSON of list until it finds a correct one, here, the first JSON that has a value lower than the given temperature.

Code :

```
getInfos = temp => {
    return [
        {
            value: 95,
            description: 'Sunny',
            image: sunny
        },
        {
            value: 85,
            description: 'Partly Cloudy',
            image: partly
        },
        {
            value: 75,
            description: 'Cloudy',
            image: cloudy
        },
        {
            value: -Infinity,
            description: 'Rainy',
            image: rainy
        },
    ].find(weather => temp >= weather.value)
}
```

**Changing the temperature**

To change your temperature, simply add a parameter saying by how much you want to vary it :

```
<div className="upButton" onClick={this.changeTemp(1)}>+</div>
<div className="downButton" onClick={this.changeTemp(-1)}>-</div>
```

Then, make a function that receives both this parameter and the click event (even if you're not using it). this function should also update the information about the image and the description using `getInfos`:

```
changeTemp = value => ev => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
        temp: prevState.temp + value,
        ...this.getInfos(prevState.temp + value)
    }))
}
```

Full code :

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday',].map(day => ({
                day,
                temp: 100
            }))
        }
    }

    cardClicked = card => event => {
        this.setState({ data })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="cards">
                    {this.state.data.map(card => <WeatherCard key={card.day} data={card}></WeatherCard>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

import sunny from '../img/sunny.png';
import partly from '../img/partly.png';
import cloudy from '../img/cloudy.png';
import rainy from '../img/rainy.png';

class WeatherCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const { temp } = props

        this.state = {
            temp
        }

        getInfos(temp)
    }

    getInfos = temp => {
        return [
            {
                value: 95,
                description: 'Sunny',
                image: sunny
            },
            {
                value: 85,
                description: 'Partly Cloudy',
                image: partly
            },
            {
                value: 75,
                description: 'Cloudy',
                image: cloudy
            },
            {
                value: -Infinity,
                description: 'Rainy',
                image: rainy
            },
        ].find(weather => temp >= weather.value)
    }

    changeTemp = value => ev => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ 
            temp: prevState.temp + value,
            ...this.getInfos(prevState.temp + value)
        }))
    }

    render() {
        const { day } = this.props
        const { temp, image, description } = this.state

        return (
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-head">{day}</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h1>{temp}</h1>
                    <img src={image} alt={description}></img>
                    <p>{description}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <div className="upButton" onClick={this.changeTemp(1)}>+</div>
                    <div className="downButton" onClick={this.changeTemp(-1)}>-</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

EDIT :

Here's an even shorter version of your `getInfos` function using array deconstruction, just because :

```
getInfos = temp => 
    [ 
        [95, 'Sunny', sunny],
        [85, 'Partly Cloudy', partly],
        [75, 'Cloudy', cloudy],
        [-Infinity, 'Rainy', rainy]
    ].find(([value]) => temp >= value)
```

Comment: There were a couple bugs in what you gave me but overall this is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I do not understand how a Map will help us in that case. Since every result is a temperature range and not just : `95`. Can you show me your solution ?

@user3158670 Sorry, the code is partly not tested, I hope the explanation made it up for you

Comment: ah nuts... I just scanned the filter function and believed I saw an equals sign. nevermind :/

Comment: I made the `getInfos` function even shorter if you are interested ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

--- App.js ---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WeatherCard from './components/WeatherCard';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday',].map((day, i) => ({
                day,
                temp: (100 - (i*10))
            }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="cards">
                    {this.state.data.map(card => <WeatherCard key={card.day} data={card}></WeatherCard>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

--- WeatherCard.js ---

```
import sunny from '../img/sunny.png';
import partly from '../img/partly.png';
import cloudy from '../img/cloudy.png';
import rainy from '../img/rainy.png';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class WeatherCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const { day, temp } = props.data

        this.state = {
            day,
            temp,
            ...this.getData(temp)
        }
    }

    getData = temp => {
        return [
            {
                value: 95,
                description: 'Sunny',
                image: sunny
            },
            {
                value: 85,
                description: 'Partly Cloudy',
                image: partly
            },
            {
                value: 75,
                description: 'Cloudy',
                image: cloudy
            },
            {
                value: -Infinity,
                description: 'Rainy',
                image: rainy
            },
        ].find(weather => temp >= weather.value)
    }

    changeTemp = value => ev => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ 
            temp: prevState.temp + value,
            ...this.getData(prevState.temp + value)
        }))
    }

    render() {
        const { day } = this.props.data
        const { temp, image, description } = this.state

        return (
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-head">{day}</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h1>{temp}</h1>
                    <img src={image} alt={description}></img>
                    <p>{description}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <div className="upButton" onClick={this.changeTemp(1)}>+</div>
                    <div className="downButton" onClick={this.changeTemp(-1)}>-</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default WeatherCard;
```

If I remember correctly I think the biggest issues with what you provided (@Treycos) were reference bugs ('this' not placed where it should have been) - etc. But some really good stuff you provided, thanks again!